# D3.js changing Integer axis to String

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to change the x axis of this graph that I found online from int to string. How do I do it??

[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOfUF.png)

```
var x0 = Math.max(-d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.drugs; }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.drugs; }));
    x.domain(["Drug A", "Drug B", "Drug C", "Drug D"]); // I tried editing this but it's not showing on my graph
    y.domain([0, 250])
```

[Link to Online graph(Click Me)](http://plnkr.co/edit/5g4lUXnJa3pmWEfFq8rq?p=preview)

Comment: Is your x-axis Scale is linear or ordinal scale ? If its linear why don't you use ordinal scale, which will good for string.

Comment: @NithinCVPoyyil I tried changing from linear to ordinal for my x axis. It sort of works but it only accepts 2 strings (for my case I need to add as many strings as possible)  --> http://i.imgur.com/gdCTbbS.png. Any advice on this?

Comment: @NithinCVPoyyil Sorry for stealing your comment and making an answer out of it - but it was a bit too long to fit in an another comment. Thanks for mentioning the ordinal scale!

Comment: :)  Learn, share & Develop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in a comment by @Nithin CV Poyyil, an ordinal scale can help, e.g.:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(['A','B','C']).rangePoints([0,1]);
```

Then you can do things like:

```
x('B') // --> 0.5
```

Please note that you have various options for the `range`, like `rangePoints`, `rangeBands`...

[--> see here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal)